# Nginx Load Balancer not redirecting to post login URL

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am trying to configure Nginx load balancer with a Spring Web app , With CSRF/Spring Security enabled. The Login Page is exempted from any authentication.

I configured just 1 Tomcat with NGINX , and deployed the app as ROOT.war , localhost:90/LoginPage.jsp is loading fine , But after login its showing a error page 504 Gateway timeout error.

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {    
    upstream kevin_server { 
    server localhost:8080;  
    ip_hash;       
    }
    server {
        listen       90;
        server_name  localhost; 
        location / {
            proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;     
            proxy_pass http://kevin_server;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
               
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**I am new with NGINX , not able figure out what to do next !!**